# RoR how to create forms with drill down

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a clients table and a projects table.
I would like to create a form where the user first selects the client from a drop-down list and then selects from a drop-down list of projects belonging to that client.

Could you please point me to some "how-to" information.

Thanks

PS - I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap in the app if that's useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to do this :-

Here is an example which will show you the license div if you have selected Type1 from the dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user_account_type').change(function(){
        if ($('form select option:selected').val() == 'Type1'){
            $('.license').show();
          }else{
            $('.license').hide();
        }
    });
});
```